# javascript won't work when included

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have some weird problem with a javascript file. when I use it inside my html file, just by writing it within the script tags, it works just fine. but when I include it with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/[my bundle]/js/login.js') }}"></script>,
```

It doesn't work anymore. Any idea why ?

There is the code, even if I don't think it comes from this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $(".login");

    $('#lol').click(function(){

    $( ".login_background" ).fadeToggle( "700", "linear" );
    $( ".login" ).fadeToggle( "700", "linear" );
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}',
        success: function(response){
            $('.login_header_full').html(response)
            }
        });
    });

    $(".login_close").click(function(){
        container.hide();
        $(".login_background").hide();
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
        var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
    $( ".login" ).fadeToggle( "700", "linear" );
        $( ".login_background" ).fadeToggle( "700", "linear" );
    }
    });

    $(".login_background").hide();
});
```

Comment: make sure, you insert it after the jQuery <script>

Comment: Check with noConflict  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: it is visible when you display source code ?

Comment: Yes, the code is exactly the same.

Comment: so what does not work ? what error do you experience ?

Comment: Well, when I write the code inside of the HTML page, it works jut fine: when i click on the "connect button", a login window appears, just as it should. but when I include the exact same js code from an external file, it doesn't work anymore: when I click on the same connect button, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you install your assets by `php app/console assets:install`? Is the path for the script file correct?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me that the file location of your javascript file is not where your `script` tag is pointing to.  If you are not using Assetic or anything like that, then your js files must be in the `web` directory.  So in your case, place your file in a directory within

```
{SymfonyRoot}/web/.../login.js
```

For example, you could create a `web/js` directory, and then your code would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/login.js') }}"></script>
```

Or, if you want to keep the same path that you posted in your question, then your login.js file must be located at

```
{SymfonyRoot}/web/bundles/[myBundle]/js/login.js
```

This will allow you to use this script location:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/[my bundle]/js/login.js') }}"></script>
```

Remember that your `web` directory is your DocumentRoot, so all public files must be located in the this directory if you want to be able to access them on your site.